# Migrate a Facebook Page to its own account

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I created a Facebook Page for my company in my own Facebook account, and now I would like to migrate it to its own account. I would like to keep the custom URL and followers that we currently have.

How do I go about removing this Page from being linked to my personal account and to its own?

Answer (score 4):

What you are thinking of doing is not possible.

The only move possible is a business account converted to a personal account (this is not reversible).

A personal account is to be used by an individual only though.

What you can try to do is email support@facebook.com and see if they will allow you to create a business account (since you already created page, the normal process is page then business account). From there *maybe* just maybe you can have the business account handle control of the page freeing your personal account.

> Please be aware that managing multiple
>   accounts is a serious violation of
>   Facebook’s Terms of Use. If we
>   determine that an individual has more
>   than one account, we reserve the right
>   to terminate all of their accounts.

So be sure you explain carefully and clearly in your email.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new account and change the admin roles on the page so that the new account is the admin. I did this with my page and all of my followers, pictures, and comments stayed the same. To do this, you just go to your page's home, select the 'Settings' button (the cog-looking button in the upper right corner), choose your page under 'Use Facebook as:', select the drop-down arrow of 'Edit Page' from your page menu, select 'Admin Roles'. You will then be taken to the 'Managing Admins| Facebook' page where you can add a new admin (you will have to verify that you accept the admin role with the new account) and then, once the new admin has been verified, you can delete your account from the admin list.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can no turn your longer account a business page using your existing information like In the past you either need personally request Facebook profile convert into a page or create a page from scratch